# Printing screenshot within ExtentReport

Tags: java, extentreports, selenium-extent-report

I don't understand why my screenshots are not appearing in my ExtentReport locally (I haven't tried from a build server yet). Here is the TestNG @AfterMethod where the takeScreenShot method is called:-

```
@AfterMethod
public void afterMethod(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
    APPLICATION_LOGS.debug("Running @AfterMethod");
    switch (result.getStatus()) {
        case ITestResult.FAILURE:
            childTest.fail(result.getThrowable())
                    .addScreenCaptureFromPath((takeScreenShot(result.getMethod().getMethodName())));
            try {
                childTest.info("<a href='https://mywebsite.com/fabrix/logs/s/" + webSessionId + "'" + "target=_'blank'>Data control logs</a>");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                childTest.info("Unable to get Session ID");
            }//.....more code
```

And here is the called method:

```
private String takeScreenShot(String methodName) {
    String path = System.getProperty("user.dir") + "\\target\\reports\\screenshots\\" + methodName + ".png";
    try {
        File screenshotFile = ((TakesScreenshot) driver).getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
        FileUtils.copyFile(screenshotFile, new File(path));
    } catch (Exception e) {
        APPLICATION_LOGS.error("Could not write screenshot" + e);
    }
    return path;
}
```

And the report:

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I examine the image using Chrome developer tools and the path is perfect and image is saved in the same directory as the report. So why not showing?

From IntelliJ:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the screenshot path specified needs to be relative -to- the reports path.  I found that out the hard way myself.  While the screenshot is indeed being taken and stored where you think it is, since it's the exact same location as the report, simply leave-off the path leading-up to the filename.

In my output, I place the report file in the target\reports folder off the project folder, but then I have a target\reports\screenshots folder, so when I attach the screenshots to the test object, I only specify "screenshots\filename.png"  It would not work when I tried the full path.

Comment: thanks @Bill Hileman.  I've placed my Extent Report as a sub folder of the target folder structure as you suggest but the only way I can get the screenshot into its intended folder is by using the fielpath in the amended question (see above) and it still doesn't appear in the report.  Do I need to amend the extent-config.xml?

Comment: when I look at the source of the Extent Report, the path to the image is spot on! Frustrating

Comment: It's because you are still prepending `System.getProperty("user.dir")` to the path.  The path needs to be relative, NOT absolute.  If you put the report in your app's target folder, i.e. `System.getProperty("user.dir") + "/target/report.html"` then if you want to place the screenshot in the SAME folder, you do not specify any filespec AT ALL except the filename.  If you want to make a screenshot folder under /target called /target/screenshot then the passed path for the screenshot should ONLY start with `screenshot/youroutputscreenshotfile.png` not the entire path.

Comment: It just occurred to me that I might still be confusing you - you DO need a full, absolute path when you CAPTURE the screenshot, but when you pass the path to attach it to the report, it needs to be a RELATIVE path.