# ExtentReports doesn't save the screenshot with the report

Tags: java, selenium, extentreports

Hello I am trying to capture screenshot of failed test cases using selenium webdriver with Maven and TestNG with following code, it does generate the screenshot in my project but doesn't get included inside the report what do I need to change in the code?

```
 WebDriver driver;
ExtentReports extent;
ExtentTest logger;
@BeforeTest
public void setUp() {
    extent = new ExtentReports("C:\\Users\\IdeaProjects\\p\\test-output\\report.html", true);
    extent.loadConfig(new File("C:\\Users\\IdeaProjects\\p\\test-output\\extent-config.xml"));
    driver = new FirefoxDriver();
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(30, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.get("http://www.google.com");
}
@Test
public void testExtentReports() {
    logger = extent.startTest("testExtentReports");
    Assert.assertTrue(false);
}
@AfterMethod
public void tearDown(ITestResult result) throws IOException {
    if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.FAILURE) {
        logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test Case Failed is "+result.getName());
        logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, "Test Case Failed is "+result.getThrowable());
        String screenshotPath = TestMine.getScreenshot(driver, result.getName());
        logger.log(LogStatus.FAIL, logger.addScreenCapture(screenshotPath));
    } else if(result.getStatus() == ITestResult.SKIP) {
        logger.log(LogStatus.SKIP, "Test Case Skipped is "+result.getName());
    }
    extent.endTest(logger);
}
public static String getScreenshot(WebDriver driver, String screenshotName) throws IOException {
    String dateName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss").format(new Date());
    TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
    File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
    // after execution, you could see a folder "FailedTestsScreenshots" under src folder
    String destination = "ss/" + screenshotName+dateName+".png";
    File finalDestination = new File(destination);
    FileUtils.copyFile(source, finalDestination);
    return destination;
}
@AfterTest
public void endReport() {
    extent.flush();
    extent.close();
    driver.quit();
}
```

I found a solution here but i am not quite sure how to implement this with my code:
[Printing screenshot within ExtentReport](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52078525/printing-screenshot-within-extentreport)

Comment: What is your extend report version?

Comment: it is version 5.0.9

Answer (score 0):

You can do,

```
logger.log(Status.FAIL, MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromPath(completeImagePath).build());
```

Here, completeImagePath should be the absolute full path to the screenshot file.
For e.g. in your case, it would be,

```
String completeImagePath = System.getProperty("user.dir") + File.separator + destination;
```

If you want to embed the screenshot in the report itself, then you can do below:

```
String dateName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMddhhmmss").format(new Date());
TakesScreenshot ts = (TakesScreenshot) driver;
File source = ts.getScreenshotAs(OutputType.FILE);
// after execution, you could see a folder "FailedTestsScreenshots" under src folder
String destination = "ss/" + screenshotName+dateName+".png";
File finalDestination = new File(destination);
FileUtils.copyFile(source, finalDestination);
    
    byte[] encoded = null;
    try {
        encoded = Base64.encodeBase64(FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(source));
    } catch (IOException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    logger.log(Status.FAIL,
            MediaEntityBuilder.createScreenCaptureFromBase64String(new String(encoded, StandardCharsets.US_ASCII)).build());
```